# Spring, autowired jdbcTemplate is null when called from main method

Tags: spring

My application needs a static main method that is called from its JAR file on a server.  If main is static the methods it calls, as well as the fields must be static.  The problem is, my jdbcTemplate is autowired and is null when static (I understand this does not work).  Either I remove 'static' from my main and I cannot call it from the JAR, or I make everything in the class 'static' and the jdbcTemplate is null.  What is the best solution to this issue.

Thanks in advance.

*Note that main is not static in this example, when I run it on the server it says, 'main' must be static.  Please keep this in mind for any solution.

```
public class Purge {

 @Autowired
 protected JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

 private int PURGE_DAYS = 14;

/**
 * @param args
 */
public void main(String[] args) {
    loadContext();
    purge();
}

ApplicationContext loadContext() {
    return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext-purge.xml");
}

public void purge() {
    jdbcTemplate.execute("blah blah blah");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `main` method is not `static`. If it was, it wouldn't be possible to call non-static `purge()`. Something is missing from your code. Aren't you calling `new Purge()` by any chance? If so, Spring is unaware of that instance and won't autowire anything.
2. Once you load the context you must obtain an instance of `Purge` from that context:

   ```
   Purge purge = loadContext().getBean(Purge.class)
   ```

Comment: That is the issue, if I make main static I must make purge and therefore jdbcTemplate static, which in turn makes my jdbcTemplate null.

Comment: @nukaCola: No. Make `main()` static and use code snippet above to load your `Purge` bean.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access a bean from your main method, you could try using `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext#getBean`:

```
ApplicationContext context = loadContext();

this.jdbcTemplate = (JdbcTemplate) context.getBean("myJdbcBeanName");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no choice but to main static, below is elegant method do it "Spring" way.

```
   @Component
    public class Purge{

     @Autowired
     protected JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

        public void purge(){
                  jdbcTemplate.execute("blah blah blah");

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
             ApplicationContext context = 
                    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("somthing.xml");
            Purge p = context.getBean(Purge.class);
            p.purge();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.  I found it easier to get the jdbcTemplate bean, this was my solution.

```
public class Purge {

private static int PURGE_DAYS = 14;

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    purge((JdbcTemplate) loadContext().getBean("jdbcTemplate"));
}

static ApplicationContext loadContext() {
    return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext-purge.xml");
}

public static void purge(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    jdbcTemplate.execute("blah blah blah");
}
```

}